# How to center this scrollview in page mode, with page previews?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I wanted to center this page view of a `UIScrollView`, but somehow it is misaligned. I checked `use autoresizing` in `storyboard`, but the views origins seem to be off by half a screen.

How do I fix it? Also what does the "prototyping" measurement in size inspector mean? Does it mean where the `UIImageView` was dropped on `UIWindow`? I centered it in `UIWindow`

[image]

```
CGRect frame = self.scrollView.bounds;
CGRect newFrame = self.scrollView.bounds;
newFrame.origin.y = 0.0;
newFrame.origin.x = frame.size.width*page;

frame = newFrame;
//inset for previewing next page
frame = CGRectInset(frame, 10.0, 0.0);

//UIImageView is subview of scrollView
UIImageView* newPageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
    [UIImage imageNamed:[self.pageImages objectAtIndex:page]]];

[newPageView setContentMode: UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
newPageView.frame = frame;
[self.scrollView addSubview:newPageView];

[self.pageViews insertObject:newPageView atIndex:page];
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: It looks like a question about how to use Interface Builder (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/interface-builder/) so there might be no code...

Comment: @Azat I updated with code. This actually is part of an online tutorial. I just modified for Objective C with Xcode 6. I then found this TN from Apple wrt autolayout and scrollview:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html

Comment: @Gyuri this is a screenshot from the Xcode autolayout debugger, instead of IB itself.

Comment: "where the UIImageView was dropped on UIWindow? I centered it in UIWindow" Well, that could be your problem. If you are even _seeing_ a UIWindow in Interface Builder, you're doing this completely wrong. UIWindow has not been present in a nib since iOS 3.

Answer (score 0):

I resized the imageView to be smaller, and moved its origin closer to (0,0) on its parent view and it worked.